# How to set height of row for node-excel-export?

Tags: node.js, excel, export-to-excel

I'm using [node-excel-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-excel-export) library for exporting excel file with NodeJS. I need to set row height but didn't find one on searching. tried to use `name:{height: xx}` but it doesn't work.

If anyone knows any way to do that will save my time.